# How did they calculate the input variable's fuzzy set in this Wikipedia article?

Tags: control-system, controller

I am looking to understand the fuzzy logic controller ,so I can design an adaptive fuzzy PID controller for an AC/DC converter.

[Wikipedia "Fuzzy control system" article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_control_system)

Here we see the table that represents the input variable's fuzzy set.

[image]

How did they calculate the numbers 0, 0.3. 0.7 and 1 and placed in that specific axes?

Comment: What makes you think they were calculated instead of being reasonable but arbitrary choices?

Comment: 9 spaced choices between + /-'¿ 1 bit

Comment: Do you mean we choose according to the plant we know?